# NumPy: better way to multiply a matrix by an array in-place?

Tags: numpy

I'm doing some work with with NumPy `array`s, but occasionally I need to multiply them by arrays.

Right now, I'm doing something like:

```
rotation_matrix = np.matrix([ ... ])
for vector in vectors:
    rotated_vec_mat = vector.T * rotation_matrix
    vector[:] = np.array(rotated_vec_mat)[0]
```

But that's ugly (and slow?).

Is there a cleaner way of doing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Might make more sense to do this:

```
vector_arr = np.concatenate([vector[np.newaxis, :] for vector in vectors], axis=0)
rotated_vector_arr = np.dot(vector_arr, rotation_matrix)
```

Then the rows of `rotated_vector_arr` are what you want them to be. You can treat the whole thing as one matrix product and have the looping done in C/Fortran by the BLAS library.

There's no need to use the matrix() class to do matrix multiplication, arrays work fine. matrix() overloads the * operator but I find it just confuses things.

Comment: Hrm… I don't understand. What does the call to `np.concatenate` do? Eg, if `vector = np.array([1,2,3])`, `np.concatenate(vector[np.newaxis, :], axis=0)` just returns `np.array([1,2,3])`.

Comment: Errr, I forgot the list comprehension in there.